# Não consigo exibir na view os dados de objeto que retornam de $http.get

Tags: angularjs, ui-router

Estou obtendo dados de uma api via $http request. Este é o meu controller.

```js
angular.module('supernovaWebApp',['ui.router'])
  .controller('professoresCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
        $http.get("http://localhost:3000/api/instructors/"+instructorId).success(function(data,status){
          console.log(data);
          $scope.professor = data;        
        });
      };
  }])
  .config(function($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider.state('instructor', {
      url: '/instructor',
      templateUrl: 'views/instructor.html',
      controller: 'professoresCtrl'
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

O objeto retorna sem erros e consigo observar o objeto no console, mas ele não renderiza na view.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
    <div  class="mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
      <div class="mdl-card__title">
        <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">{{professor.name}} {{professor.last_name}}</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
        <p>{{professor.profession}}</p>
        <i class="material-icons md-18">phone</i> {{professor.phone}}
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__menu">
        <button ng-click="delInstructor(instructor)" class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" >
          <i id="btn-archive" class="material-icons" >clear</i>
          <span class="mdl-tooltip" data-mdl-for="btn-archive">
            Arquivar
          </span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>        
</div>
```

O estranho é que quando faço o mesmo chamado para um lista de objetos, consigo exibí-los usando ng-repeat, sem problemas. Alguém sabe onde estou errando?

Print do console. O Objeto em questão é o de id 1
[image: Print do console]

Comment: `data` retorna um único objeto ou uma lista? Se possível passa o print do `console(data)``

Comment: A instrução `console.log(data);` retorna algo? Caso não, minha aposta é que seja um problema de CORS e sua chamada esteja falhando. Como não há callback para o caso de erro, você não está vendo a exceção.

Comment: O console.log retorna o objeto que deveria retornar mesmo. Assim que conseguir coloco o print da tela. @LuKsSys

Comment: @LuKsSys adicionei o print da tela.

Comment: Essa parte de html que você colocou está dentro da view ``instructor``? Se sim, faça um teste: ao invés de você configurar o controlador pelo app no angular, coloque nessa view um ng-controller indicando o controlador. Talvez sua variável ``professor`` está em outro escopo!

Comment: @ChristianFelipe já havia feito este teste. Continua na mesma. O controller está sendo definido pelo ui-router quando carrega a view instructor.

Comment: No seu exemplo não tem o atributo `ng-app` no HTML

Comment: @Sorack ele está na html index. Dentro do index tenho <div ui-view> para renderizar as views que o router toma conta.

Comment: @ViniciusScaramel veja se voce consegue algum retorno de informação com o "{{data.professor.name}}".